# Better overview of different sheets in Microsoft Excel

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel

I have a MS Excel document with lots of different sheets. By default each sheets is listet at the very bottom next to each other, like this:

[image]

However, as the number of sheets grows, it's getting very confusing and I have to click a lot to the left or to the right, to find a specific sheet. Is there a way to have a better overview, like a list or something, to show me all the sheets in the document in a neat way? Also reordering the sheets would be something nice to have.

I have MS Excel 2016 64-bit.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the arrows to the left of the actual tabs. A dialog will open that lists all sheets in a regular list. IIRC you cannot reorder sheets from this dialog though.

---

That being said: If your Excel workbook gets to big to handle, Excel probably wasn’t the right tool for the job!

Comment: Useful & handy @Daniel ,,, perfect 10 :-)

Answer (score 2):

*I would like to suggest you a simple method to create Hyperlink of Sheet Name for easy navigation*.

[image]

**How it works:**

- Press *Ctrl+K* to open the *Insert Hyperlink dialog box*.
- Click the *Place in This Document button*.
- Then link to the sheet, select Sheet name from *Cell Reference* & press OK.
- In *Type the Cell reference* write the Cell address which you want to
  attach with Sheet's Hyperlink.

**Note,**

- *Repeat Step 1 to 3 for other Sheets.*
- *Using this method you can create Sheet's Name list in desire order*.